# Partition Equivalent in Julia

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica, julia

What is an equivalent for Mathematica's `Partition` function in Julia?

Mathematica's `Partition[list,n]` takes an array and partitions it into non-overlapping sub-list of length `n`. On the other hand, the partition function in Julia takes an array and gives all the partitions of that array into `n` sub-sets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't this do what you want?

```
x = [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f]
n = 2
reshape(x, (n, div(length(x), n)))
```

Comment: This answer won't work if the length doesn't cleanly divide into subarrays of length `n`, e.g. `x = [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f,:g]`, `n=2` will fail. You also get a matrix, instead of an array-of-arrays.

Comment: @IainDunning, I agree, it doesn't mimic the `Partition` function in Mathematica. Given @Ali's use, however, it might be what is needed.

Answer (score 11):

So in Mathematica:

```
In[1]:= Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 2]
Out[1]= {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}
```

but in Julia the `partitions` function has a very different meaning:

```
x = [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f]
first(partitions(x,2))
#2-element Array{Array{Symbol,1},1}:
# [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e]
# [:f]
```

Its the set of all 2-partitions of the set. To get what you want you could do something like

```
yourpart(x,n) = {{x[i:min(i+n-1,length(x))]} for i in 1:n:length(x)}
```

and

```
julia> yourpart([:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f], 2)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 {:a,:b}
 {:c,:d}
 {:e,:f}

julia> yourpart(x,4)
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 {[:a,:b,:c,:d]}
 {[:e,:f]}
```

Comment: To avoid deprecated warnings (as of Julia 0.4.5), you can write this as `yourpart(x, n) = [x[i:min(i+n-1,length(x))] for i in 1:n:length(x)]`

Answer (score 4):

This also works

```
partitioneddata=[data[n:n+pfac] for n=1:offset:length(data)-pfac];
```

where:

- pfac is how "long" you want your new arrays to each be

and

- offset is by how many positions you want each new array to be offset by

This can be seen in the following example:

We want to partition [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] into new arrays of length=2 with each array shifted by offset=1.

```
pfac=2
offset=1
partitioneddata=[data[n:n+pfac] for n=1:offset:length(data)-pfac]
8-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}: 
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[3,4,5]
[4,5,6]
[5,6,7]
[6,7,8]
[7,8,9]
[8,9,10]
```

I know I'm a bit late to the party but hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This approach should (i) be more memory efficient and (ii) allow e.g. 53 data points to be split into groups of 10.

```
"""
returns ranges (i.e. indices to split the data).
"""
function partition_array_indices(nb_data::Int, nb_data_per_chunk::Int)
    nb_chunks = ceil(Int, nb_data / nb_data_per_chunk)
    ids = UnitRange{Int}[]
    for which_chunk = 1:nb_chunks
        id_start::Int = 1 + nb_data_per_chunk * (which_chunk - 1)
        id_end::Int = id_start - 1 + nb_data_per_chunk
        if id_end > nb_data
            id_end = nb_data
        end
        push!(ids, id_start:id_end)
    end
    return ids
end
```

Example use:

```
x = collect(linspace(0, 1, 53))
nb_data_per_chunk = 10
ids = partition_array_indices(length(x), nb_data_per_chunk)

# get first chunk, 10 elements
x[ids[1]]
# get last chunk, just 3 elements
x[ids[end]]
```

Comment: I think now you can simply call 
```
ids = Iterators.partition(x, nb_data_per_chunk)
```
and the standard library function will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

In case others also run across the need for the related task of breaking an array into n parts:

```
function nfolds(x::AbstractArray, n::Int)
    s = length(x) / n
    [x[round(Int64, (i-1)*s)+1:min(length(x),round(Int64, i*s))] for i=1:n]
end

julia> map(length, npartition(1:21, 6))
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 3
 3
 4
 4
 3
```